# Запятая при "между тем(,) как"

Tags: запятые, вводные-слова, союзы

Встречаю разные варианты (с запятыми и без), но не могу понять разницу.
Ниже условный пример:

> Не могу пока уловить связи между тем(,) как произошло вот это(,) и тем(,) как
>   произошло вот это…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В приведенном примере все указанные запятые нужны – они отделяют главное предложение (*Не могу уловить связи между тем и тем*) от придаточных.

Но есть сложный союз "между тем как".

Розенталь, параграф 34:

6. Не расчленяются сложные союзы *в то время как*, ***между тем как***, *тогда как*, *словно как*, а также простые союзы и примыкающая к ним усилительная частица (*даже если, лишь когда, лишь только, только лишь, едва лишь, едва только, чуть только* и т. п.): Почему-то в ожидании его на месте, в то время как он бродил по роще, она увидела себя взрослой, а его — маленьким (Фед.); …Встретивши Гапку, начал бранить, зачем она шатается без дела, **между тем как** она тащила крупу в кухню (Г.); …Она осознала в себе силы и решилась бороться с мужем, без слёз и жалоб, требовать, тогда как до сих пор она только плакала (Пом.); Лишь только Божие проклятье исполнилось, с того же дня природы жаркие объятья навек остыли для меня (Л.); Словно как мать над сыновней могилой, стонет кулик над равниной унылой (Н.); Но едва только он отъехал от Багратиона, как силы изменили ему (Л. Т.).

Answer (score 1):

*Как произошло вот это* — придаточное со своим подлежащим и сказуемым. Соответственно, его нужно отделить запятыми.

Связи (*какие? между чем?*) между тем. || Входит в главное предложение, так как можно задать вопрос.

Запятая может не ставится, если *между тем как* означает *в то время как*:
*Встретивши Гапку, начал бранить, зачем она шатается без дела, между тем как она тащила крупу в кухню.* || Но сейчас это значение начинает устаревать. Даже на Грамоте этот союз не представлен.